# How to load a .xml file with URLVariables

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, urlloader, urlvariables

How to load a .xml file with URLVariables using AS3

example:  file
example.xml?varsHere

```
var loa:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loa.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gocom);
loa.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, gotError);
loa.load(new URLRequest("example.xml"));


function gotError(event:IOErrorEvent):void{
    trace("INVALID");
}//  function gotError


function gocom(event:Event){

    var userxml:XML = new XML(loa.data);
    XML.ignoreProcessingInstructions = false;
    userxml = new XML(loa.data);

}


//   INVALID
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to specify _which_ xml file you want the application to load using URLVariables? Your post doesn't make much sense as you don't need to use URLVariables to load an XML file, it sounds like you're doing more work for a task that can already be done very easily.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like I'm going about it wrong but I wanted to know if this could work.

Comment: Almost anything can work if you know what you're trying to accomplish. ;)

Comment: See what the error is. trace(event.text);